# Question is about combination of cells in series

Tags: electric-circuits, potential

If cells are connected in series with positive terminal of one cell with negative terminal of other cell what is the potential difference between those two terminals..? Is that not zero.?

Comment: If they are connected with a conductor, they will have zero potential difference, as long as we neglect the resistivity of whatever is connecting them.

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of cells are being discussed? Do you mean galvanic cells (batteries)? What are they connected with?

Comment: Whichever you prefer... I got this doubt while reading the derivation of cells in series as per 12th ncert physics book...